# How to change the BadCredentialsException,UserNameNotFound Exception Messages in Json format from custom Authentication Provider class

Tags: java, angularjs, json, spring, spring-security

I have tried different things but nothing works for me till now and still not able to send the exception responses from my custom authentication provider in json format.I am using xml configuration

Things i have tried

1.customAuthenticationFailureHandler

2 CustomEntryPoint

3.CustomAccessDenied

I have angular js on front end and i want a json message if authentication fail but right now i thowing BadCredentialsException,UsernotFoundException and getting a HTML data in rest client.

Any help...

Answer (score 0):

okies so I got the answer to my question...

you have to write your customAuthenticationEntryPoint class which implements AuthenticationEntryPoint interface

and in your securtiy-config.xml file

you have to add **entry-point-ref="restAuthenticationEntryPoint"**

```
    <http auto-config='true' use-expressions="true"
       entry-point-ref="restAuthenticationEntryPoint">
       <http-basic entry-point-ref="restAuthenticationEntryPoint"/>
       <intercept-url pattern="/user" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />
       <access-denied-handler ref="securityAccessDeniedHandler" />
       <form-login authentication-success-handler-ref="mySuccessHandler"
       authentication-failure-handler-ref="authenticationFailureHandler" /></http>
```

Then main point to notice in here is you have to provide *entry-point-ref* in both the *http* and *http-basic* tag.